# What rights do minors have in Indiana

Tags: criminal-law, property, family-law, indiana, juvenile-law

I am 20 years old and my younger brother, still a minor at 16, is battling with our parents over them seizing his property without any real cause, and refusing to return any of it, clearly outlining how he’s never getting any of it back period.

This is in the middle of a matter of our parents hating us like no parent could, and I suspect that is why the stuff was taken, not for the interest of his safety or anything of the like.

He purchased most of the items involved with his own money, which he earned from a job he held at a local restaurant, the most valuable of which being a laptop purchased for $1,100. That laptop is also the only way he can access much of anything he owns online. They have also taken the door from his room, placed a camera in his room, and constantly watch him throughout the day, effectively robbing him of his privacy, again without a legitimate cause.

Is what our parents did unlawful by any means? What can we do if it is?

Comment: In Indiana, USA, a 20 year old is not a minor except in a couple of areas such as the purchase of alcohol, for example.

Comment: My apologies, needed to clarify that 20 was my own age. The brother in question is 16

Comment: FWIW, just as a heads up, the answer is more involved and complicated than you might expect.

Comment: Related but not necessarily identical: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/24455/in-the-usa-do-parents-have-the-right-to-control-their-childrens-possessions?rq=1

Comment: My concern is how Indiana addresses it, because i’ve come up with nothing in my search.