# Can parents compel children to give them money?

Tags: property

In other words, can parents force children to agree to fines by threatening them with a loss of privileges?

I know that parents cannot take money from their children as shown in [this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/24474/48352). However, that says nothing about compelling children to give them money through privilege restrictions or other means.

Comment: Can a merchant compel me to give him money? Yes, if it is to give me something that I do not have a right to; no, if it is to give me something that I already have a right to. What do you mean by "compel"; or, for what purpose does the parent compel the giving of money?

Comment: Where? The law is different in different places. Also, by "children" do you mean people who are under the age of majority or do you mean people who have a parent-child relationship with each other who could be adults?

Comment: "children" refers to minors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can children own money?**

That is a complex question in many legislations. Children may be able to own money and other property, in their own right, yet be under the legal guardianship of their parents.

- Parents can generally control how minors spend their money.
  (A child saying *"Great-uncle left me a million bucks in his will? Great, let's buy a hundred tons of chocolate."* would be blocked by the parents and that would be upheld by a court.)
- Parents may be required to take care to preserve the property of their children.
  (A parent saying *"Great-uncle left you a million bucks in his will? I'll invest it in lottery tickets, one of them is bound to be a winner."* might be blocked by a court.)
- Children with their own income may be required to contribute to household expenses.
  (A parent saying *"So you got a summer job? Put your wages into the tin for the summer rent."* may be upheld by a court.)

In your specific case, it would matter where you live, where the money comes from, and possibly how old you are.